# How to make my code detect a royal flush and straight?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an assignment that needs me to make a code that pulls a 5 cards at a time until it gets a flush, royal flush and straight. But I only figured out the flush. Can any of you help me get that royal and straight in?

Here is my code so far:

```
from collections import namedtuple
from random import shuffle

Card = namedtuple("Card", "suit, rank")

class Deck:
    suits = '♦♥♠♣'
    ranks = '23456789JQKA'

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = [Card(suit, rank) for suit in self.suits for rank in self.ranks]
        shuffle(self.cards)

    def deal(self, amount):
        return tuple(self.cards.pop() for _ in range(amount))

flush = False
while not flush:
    deck = Deck()

    while len(deck.cards) > 5:
        hand = deck.deal(5)
        # (Card(suit='♣', rank='7'), Card(suit='♠', rank='2'), Card(suit='♥', rank='4'), Card(suit='♥', rank='K'), Card(suit='♣', rank='3'))

        if len(set(card.suit for card in hand)) > 1:
            print(f"No Flush: {hand}")
            continue

        print(f"Flush: {hand}")
        flush = True
        break
```

Comment: For stright you could sort the cards and then check if that set is in ranks, for royal flush, check if the srted cards match the last cards in rank and that its also a flush

Answer (score 0):

You already have code to check if a hand is a flush, so now all you need to check is if the cards are all unique and all cards exist in [10, J, Q, K, A].

Checking uniqueness can be done in a few ways but one quick way for me is to use a quick temporary list with unique values added only:

```
temp_list = []
[temp_list.append(card.rank) for card.rank in hand if card.rank not in temp_list]
```

Then check the len of temp_list to ensure it is still equal to 5, verifying that all 5 cards are unique.

Then we need to iterate through the values to ensure that all 5 cards are in the subset [10, J, Q, K, A] in a similiar fashion:

```
royal = true
for card in hand:
    if card.rank not in [10, J, Q, K, A]:
        royal = false
```

So now you have uniquness, and you have a bool that tells you if the hand is royal or not. If both of these things are true, accompanied by a true value from your flush logic, then you know its a royal flush.

**EDIT**

I'm just realizing too late that the check for uniqueness is not needed. When you create the cards you iterate through the suits and ranks (which is missing a '10' value btw, I used "T") so therefore in Cards there are no duplicates. Therefore if we checked for a flush and received one, then we know there are no non-unique cards as we cannot .pop() two of the same cards. So really just checking for royalty after we have verified a flush is needed.

Comment: the OP using set will be much faster then making a temp list.  also for your last part, if i had 5 jacks, i would pass your test for royal .......but thats not a royal it just means none of my cards were non royal cards

Comment: That's why we test for uniqueness before we test for royalty. And you're right the set method is faster than the temp list!